# Show me the numbers and return Null in place of text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wishing to get the data shown in coln B when using coln A - in essence show me the numbers and return Null in place of text using SQL Server 2016.

```
Coln A     
123       
qw       
Null        
456      
aa

Coln B   
123   
Null     
Null    
456    
Blank
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: sql server or mysql ? What did you try ?

Comment: What's the expected result for the value XYZ123?

Comment: You say null, but want <blank> for 'aa'?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135878/sql-servers-isnumeric-function

Comment: This is not a question but a request for free work from where I see it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I'm not sure your question is entirely correct. However the following SQL Fiddle returns the results you have provided.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/abc39/2

```
select case
  when IsNumeric(ColnA) = 1 then ColnA
  when ColnA = 'aa' then 'Blank'
  else NULL end as ColnB
from MyTable
```